# appending an entry number to FileSystemWatcher output

Tags: vb.net, winforms, math, filesystemwatcher

Okay,

Probably going to be seen as an extremely amature post here, I'm not really skilled in VB or much of a programmer but i'm on a "learn by doing" drive.

I'm developing an application which creates directories for a user, and tracks the directories created and the changes to these directories using FileSystemWatcher.

I've got this little snippet so far (Updated in answer you your comments Jimi):

Private Sub of Button_Click:

```
    watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
    watchfolder.Path = TodaysScanFolder
    watchfolder.Filter = ""
    watchfolder.IncludeSubdirectories = True

    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or
                       IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
    watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or
                       IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes

    AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logchange
    AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf logchange

    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    btnStartScan.Enabled = False
    btnStopScan.Enabled = True
End Sub

    Public Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As _
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)

    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
        txt_folderactivity.Text &= "File " & e.FullPath &
                                 " has been created" & vbCrLf
    End If
    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted Then
        txt_folderactivity.Text &= "File " & e.FullPath &
                                " has been deleted" & vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub
```

With each additional activity, I want to append the output to txt_folderactivity.Text with a 1, prior to this. Then 2, 3, so on so forth.

You see this text box, on change writes output to a text file like so:

```
Private Sub txt_folderactivity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_folderactivity.TextChanged
    str = txt_folderactivity.Text
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(LogFileLoc, str, True)
End Sub
```

I would like each line/entry to that text file to begin 1, 2, 3 and so on. Plus, as I said total beginner with VB, seem to have pieced together something which looks a bit messy but is functional and will be business critical, any pointers for a good start on relevant VB learning resources would be very helpful. Thanks All

Comment: Some observations: you haven't specified which `NotifyFilters` are defined. The `Changed()` event will possibly raise more than once, depending on those filters. You are missing the `Renamed()` event. Is that intentional? The `TextChanged()` event is unnecessary. You need to update the Log, then update your Prompt (Textbox) with the last entry. How many events will your application process (*business critical*)? If +1/sec., consider refactoring for async. execution or you will lose events. When monitoring Network Paths, FSW can be unreliable.

Comment: About the numeric indexer: you just need a integer variable (class scope) which is incremented in the event handler(s) and prepended `.ToString()` to every entry.

Comment: A note about the `NotifyFilters`. When monitoring for file changes, as I previously said, the `Changed()` event will trigger twice if, for example, you specify `NotifyFilters.LastWrite` and `NotifyFilters.Size` and a watched file is modified. There's always  the possibility (although often neglected) of using more than one instance of the `FileSystemWatcher`, to receive notification of different types of .events, which usually all raise the FSW Changed() event.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I have found it more useful to prepend the time down to milliseconds (e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")`) in a log file rather than line numbers - the latter can be shown in any reasonable text editor.

Comment: Hello Jimi, I've updated my original post with the information requested. For the purpose of this application I don't need to track alterations of files like renaming, simply their creation and deletion. The final version of this will run on a number of machines, tracking probably 3000 file creations and deletions over an 8-12 hour day. What I really need is an output of number of files created in total, vs final how many files remain. Really feeling like I need to do some more in-depth reading on VB because this application is proving very challenging. Any related reading you'd recommend?

Comment: Is it the indexing feature that is causing problems (I'ld also follow @Andrew Morton advice, the time of the event is an information that can be quite usefull)? Your setup of the FSW logger is pretty much complete (maybe some adjustments could be made, the textbox event for starter). If you need a sample code, let me know.

Comment: Since, apparently, not many others are interested in this (and I don't know if I can follow up tomorrow), I posted some information and a bunch of code that can deal with your question. Give it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class that inherits from `FileSystemWatcher`.
It takes care of the configuration, enables and disables the raising of events and has basic logging and reporting capabilities.

**Configuration of `FileSystemWatcher`:**

**`.BeginInit()`** - **`.EndInit()`**
`BeginInit()` is used to prevent the raising of events before the `FileSystemWatcher` setup is completed.

[**`.SynchronizingObject`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject)
Set the `SynchronizingObject` to a Form component. Since the `FileSystemWatcher` events are marshalled from the system thread pool, this ensures that the event delegates are called on the same thread where the component is created.
If `SynchronizingObject` is null, accessing the component may result in an Exception or, worse, in a silent failure.

[**`.InternalBufferSize`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize)
The internal buffer is used to store the events register and a file path. A buffer larger that the default (8192 bytes) can prevent a buffer overflow, which compromises the rising of events. Here it's set to 32768 bytes.

**`.Path`**
For network drives/shares use UNC Paths.

---

**How to use it:**

Define a public object that references the `FileWatcher Class`:

```
Public FileWatch As FileWatcher
```

Then you can initialize it whenever you need it:

```
FileWatch = New FileWatcher("[Path to watch]", 
                            "*",  'All files
                            "[Path to LogFile]", 
                            Me,   'Synchronizing Object
                            [TextBox control used as monitor])
```

`[TextBox control used as monitor]` can be `Nothing` if none is used.

The `FileWatcher` doesn't immediately start to raise/log events; the `EnableRaisingEvents` property is set to `False` in the initialization method.
You can start and stop its activity with its methods:

```
FileWatch.StartWatcher()
FileWatch.StopWatcher()
```

Starting and stopping the `FileWatcher` is a registered (logged) activity.
A `List(Of DateTime)` is used to store these events. See the `FW_EventLogger Class`.

Other stored information is:

- Number of files Deleted
- Number of files Created
- Overall number of registered events (for comparison)
- Size of the Log File

The `ActivityReport()` property returns a simple report:

```
Dictionary(Of String, String) = FileWatcher.ActivityReport()
```

This is what the Log File looks like:

```
00000001 - 2018/02/28 21:00:25 - File D:\Temp\New Text Document.txt has been created
00000002 - 2018/02/28 21:00:29 - File D:\Temp\New Microsoft Access Database.accdb has been created
00000003 - 2018/02/28 21:00:34 - File D:\Temp\New WinZip File.zip has been created
00000004 - 2018/02/28 21:00:44 - File D:\Temp\New Microsoft Access Database.accdb has been deleted
00000005 - 2018/02/28 21:00:44 - File D:\Temp\New Text Document.txt has been deleted
00000006 - 2018/02/28 21:00:44 - File D:\Temp\New WinZip File.zip has been deleted
```

**Limitatons:**
If requested (a TextBox control reference is passed to the class initialization), the UI is updated synchronously through a synchronization object. If the UI thread is busy for some reason, the events the underlying FileSystemWatcher is buffering will pile up. This can (and since it can it will) cause the loss of events. This is the reason why the internal buffer is set to 4x the default. Anyway, it won't ever be enough if the monitored activity is high. In normal condition, it can handle 10/sec. events without problem. Beyond that, an asynchronous proxy method that makes use a FIFO queue buffer must be placed between the event listeners and the data consumers.

**Tested with**:
Visual Studio 2017, 15.8.4
.Net Framework 4.7.1

---

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Class FileWatcher
    Inherits FileSystemWatcher

    Private EventLogger As FW_EventLogger
    Private Prompt As TextBox = Nothing

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New("", "", "", Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(fswPath As String, fswFilter As String, logFile As String, SyncObject As Form, SyncPrompt As TextBox)
        Prompt = SyncPrompt
        EventLogger = New FW_EventLogger With {.LogFileName = logFile}

        SetupFileWatcher(fswPath, fswFilter, SyncObject)
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartWatcher()
        EventLogger.TimeStart.Add(DateTime.UtcNow)
        If Prompt IsNot Nothing Then
            Prompt.AppendText(String.Format("Logger Start Time: {0}" +
                                 Environment.NewLine, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()))
        End If
        EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopWatcher()
        EnableRaisingEvents = False
        EventLogger.TimeStop.Add(DateTime.UtcNow)
        If Prompt IsNot Nothing Then
            Prompt.AppendText(String.Format("Logger Stop Time: {0}" +
                                 Environment.NewLine, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ActivityReport() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            Return CreateActivityReport()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property PromptControl As TextBox
        Get
            Return Prompt
        End Get
        Set(value As TextBox)
            Prompt = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub SetupFileWatcher(fwPath As String, fwFilter As String, SyncObject As Form)
        If fwPath.Length = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        BeginInit()
        SynchronizingObject = SyncObject
        InternalBufferSize = 32768
        IncludeSubdirectories = True
        Filter = fwFilter
        Path = fwPath
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.CreationTime
        EnableRaisingEvents = False

        'Set the handler to the events you want to receive
        AddHandler Created, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf OnCreated)
        AddHandler Deleted, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf OnDeleted)
        'The other events, should they become necessary.
        'AddHandler Changed, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf OnChanged);
        'AddHandler Renamed, New RenamedEventHandler(AddressOf OnRenamed);

        EndInit()
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateActivityReport() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        With EventLogger
            Dim log As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            log.Add("Created", .FileCreated.ToString())
            log.Add("Deleted", .FileDeleted.ToString())
            log.Add("TotalEvents", .EventsLogged.ToString())
            log.Add("LogFileSize", If(File.Exists(.LogFileName), New FileInfo(.LogFileName).Length.ToString(), "N/A"))
            log.Add("StartTime", If(.TimeStart.Count > 0, .TimeStart.First().ToString(), "Not Started"))
            log.Add("LastStopTime", If(.TimeStop.Count > 0, .TimeStop.Last().ToString(), "Never"))
            log.Add("Status", If(EnableRaisingEvents = True, "Running", "Stopped"))
            Return log
        End With
    End Function

    Protected Overloads Sub OnCreated(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        Dim Msg As String = "File " & e.FullPath & " has been created"
        EventLogger.Update(Msg, FW_EventLogger.EventType.FileCreated)
        If Prompt IsNot Nothing Then
            Prompt.AppendText(Msg + Environment.NewLine)
            Prompt.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overloads Sub OnDeleted(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        Dim Msg As String = "File " & e.FullPath & " has been deleted"
        EventLogger.Update(Msg, FW_EventLogger.EventType.FileDeleted)
        If Prompt IsNot Nothing Then
            Prompt.AppendText(Msg + Environment.NewLine)
            Prompt.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
    End Sub

    'The Event Logger Class
    Private Class FW_EventLogger

        Sub New()
            TimeStart = New List(Of DateTime)
            TimeStop = New List(Of DateTime)
        End Sub

        Public Enum EventType As Integer
            FileCreated = 0
            FileDeleted
        End Enum

        Public Property FileDeleted As Integer
        Public Property FileCreated As Integer
        Public Property EventsLogged As Integer
        Public Property TimeStart As List(Of DateTime)
        Public Property TimeStop As List(Of DateTime)
        Public Property LogFileName As String

        Public Sub Update(NewEvent As String, TypeOfEvent As EventType)

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LogFileName) Then
                If TypeOfEvent = EventType.FileCreated Then FileCreated += 1
                If TypeOfEvent = EventType.FileDeleted Then FileDeleted += 1
                EventsLogged += 1
                Using LogFileWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(LogFileName, True, Encoding.UTF8)
                    LogFileWriter.WriteLine(EventsLogged.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"c) +
                                            " - {0} - {1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"), NewEvent)
                End Using
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```