# Restrictions on filesystemwatcher paths?

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

I've set up my **filesystemwatcher**, but I'm getting odd results. I've found that if I put a complete path of a directory, and set include subdirectories, then changes are channeled as they should. But what I've tried to do unsuccessfully is set my `"C:\"` drive as the path with include subdirectories.

Are there restrictions on using the main drive as a path?

I've tried every syntax of it I could, but no success. Just wondering if there's something there I don't know...comments welcome :)

Here's pertinent code if anyone wants to take a look at it. Suggestions would be great:

```
<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")>
Private Sub WatchFolders()
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kgene\source\repos\Test Program\Test Program\Resources\BakDb.accdb")

    MessageBox.Show("setting up watch folders")
    watcher = New FileSystemWatcher With {.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName Or NotifyFilters.FileName Or NotifyFilters.Attributes}
    watcher.Path = "c:\"
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf LogChange
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf LogChange
    AddHandler watcher.Deleted, AddressOf LogChange
    AddHandler watcher.Renamed, AddressOf LogChangeR

End Sub

Private Sub LogChange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kgene\source\repos\Test Program\Test Program\Resources\BakDb.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    chkCnt = 0

    Try
        str = "SELECT Base, Target FROM Backup"
        cmd.Connection = myConn
        cmd.CommandText = str
        myConn.Open()
        Dim lstReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If cntPlns = 0 Then
            myConn.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lstReader.Read()
        Do Until chkCnt = cntPlns
            If lstReader.Item(0).ToString().ToLower() = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath).ToString.ToLower() Or lstReader.Item(1).ToString().ToLower() = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath).ToString().ToLower() Then
                If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then
                    MessageBox.Show("first item changed")
                End If
                If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
                    MessageBox.Show("first item create")
                End If
                If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted Then
                    MessageBox.Show("first item delete")
                End If
            End If
            If cntPlns = 0 Then
                myConn.Close()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            lstReader.Read()
            chkCnt += 1
        Loop
        chkCnt = 0
        myConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        chkCnt = 0
        myConn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem conncecting to the database to watch your folders")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Descriptions like "tried to do unsuccessfully" are never adequate.  You need to be specific about what happened.  If you expected events to be raised and they weren't, say that.  If there was a compilation error or runtime exception, say that and provided the specific error message and where the error occurred.  Don't make use guess anything that you already know.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be understood that I'm not getting the EventArgs to verify that my path was being monitored as expected. I just set a basic message dialog to display the path of the affected file as I would make a change, such as deleting or adding a file to the watched directory. The path would never show up in dialogs. Other EventArgs would, but not the directory that should have been monitored. So I'm wondering if there is any restriction to using the "C:\" drive as a valid path.

Comment: There's not such a restriction. Something has not been setup correctly . If you show your `FileSystemWatcher` implementation, then someone can tell you what's what.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. Yes there must be something in my code that isn't right. I edited my question to add the code, so take a look at it and let me know if there's something you think that's amiss.

Comment: Move the `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True` after the code that registers the events. -- At this time, you're watching for changes for each and every file and directory in the `c:` drive (possibly, where the System in installed, the temporary folders, browser cache, user files, program files (...) are located. A single FSW can't keep up with this undefinitely. Not in the current state. You're also accessing your database in the same drive. This will cause FSW events, too. Do you really need to be notified of every change in the file system?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jimi. I moved the statement. Yes, I am receiving notification for every file event, but it was the only way I could get around being able to set a new filewatcher object for each directory I want to track. What I'm doing is checking each fileinfo directory against my database of directories, and just filtering out the ones I need to handle. You mentioned the database on the same drive...don't really have an alternative. I'm always open to suggestions if you have some.

Comment: That order adjustment seems to be working for me now. Thanks for the insight. I would like to hear any idea you have about getting around receiving all file changes. I couldn't find a way around creating a unique name for the filewatcher object which I had to declare outside my method.

Comment: How many directories are you watching? `FileSystemWatcher` is a wrapper for [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) (read the reamark section carefully). It's buffer is finite. If you combine a database access to the event handler in a, possibly, high number of events, it will overflow. When it overflows, all the events previously collected and not yet read are lost. What you can do: define a larger buffer. 32768 bytes instead of 8192. (*to be continued*)

Comment: (...) Create a class for your FSW and use a `List(Of [Class])` to instantiate a number of FSWs to cover your *watching* requirements. Try to limit the number of higher-level directories as much as possible. Move all the code that resides in the event handler in another method. Test it for some time. It things go out of balance, here's the hard part. You need to create an async handler for the code that manages the FSW events results, so that the events handlers are never blocked. A block can (and will) cause the loss of data.

Comment: It just came to mind that I've posted some notes and code about this in VB.Net: [you can find them here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006562/appending-an-entry-number-to-filesystemwatcher-output?answertab=active#tab-top). See if it can be of use.

Comment: Thanx Jimi, looks like the notes will be helpful though I'll have a steep learning curve. All the info I've found on here has been helpful. Thanx everyone.

Comment: Jimi, I am working with the    filesystemwatcher class you posted, and I'm finding that the methods in it are not supported by the class. Has there been an update that now has all the setup methods in it you used? Intellisense keeps kicking it back at me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That code is part of an example project I keep for StackOverflow. I've updated the project to Visual Studio `15.8.4`, `.Net Framework 4.7.1` (which is the original framework used). I know it works the same on Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, same FW. If you just copied the class, you need to `Import`: `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.IO`, `System.Windows.Forms`. If you can be more specific on which parts Intellisense is kicking you... :)

Comment: hmm...well, I imported the classes you listed. I get a squiggly red line under Inherits FileSystemWatcher and the related methods in the setup method. Not sure what else it could be related to. I've got 2017 VS. Hmmm, I'll keep looking it over...if you have any other suggestions feel free to offer. Oh, EnableRaisingEvents has a red line too, which is odd, because I've used it in my previous filewatcher code. --- well, I ran debug and I think I've got an initialization problem in the partial class...I've had that happen before. I'll see if I can get it squared away.

Comment: If you have squiggles under `Inherits FileSystemWatcher`, it means you haven't imported `System.IO`. Intellisense tells you why it's squiggling, though. Also, there's just one class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the

> watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

after the code that register the events as Jimi suggested. This solve the problem setting up the watched folders to register events as expected.